# Firefox snap freezes in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, snap, freeze

Firefox freezes for me almost daily, and if it does, sometime around 3 in the afternoon, or after 6 hours of work. It mostly happens while I am editing text in a text area or when I select text from a web page. I use Firefox 118.0.2 (64-Bit) (the snap version) on Ubuntu 22.04 which runs in VMWare Horizon.

I notice it getting slow for a few seconds, then a pop-up appears saying Firefox is unresponsive with the options force quit and wait (or their localized equivalents). When I click wait, Firefox remains unresponsive, and the pop-up reappears after 10 seconds. I tried to wait it out several times, up to an hour, but finally I always had to click force quit.

It might be a browser script going bezerk, but Firefox doesn't use a significant amount of CPU while it's frozen. Everything else seems unaffected.

I do admit I usually have a lot windows and tabs open (thirty-ish tabs), but this never was a problem until a few weeks ago. But I can't pinpoint the start of the problem to a date or a change in the system.

Around the time of the freeze, I see this apparmor message in /var/log/syslog, but I don't know if it is related (its timestamp is roughly a minute earlier than the freeze):

```
Oct 20 14:41:43 myhostname dbus-daemon[88985]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.42" pid=90523 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=89403 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: I experience the same problem, on Debian unstable, with Firefox 118 and 119. No clue what's going on.

Comment: I tried disabling hardware acceleration as recommended here, still waiting for Firefox to hang again: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hangs-or-not-responding#w_turn-off-hardware-acceleration

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration didn't help.

Comment: It seems better in Firefox 120. I don't think the root cause is fixed, I still get a short freeze occasionally, but Firefox no longer gets stuck in a "application is not responding" loop.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent snap version of FF is 119.0.

```
snap refresh --list
sudo snap refresh firefox
```

Previously posted answers are ill-advised or unresponsive in my opinion.  The symptoms you describe sound like a lack of resources issue.  Mozilla applications use a lot of resources especially if a lot of plugins are installed.

Ubuntu recommends migrating to the snap store for many apps including Firefox.  This was more or less mandated starting with Ubuntu 22.04.  I see that you've done that.  Advice to install Firefox using the apt tool will cause you more problems.

My answer is especially worth serious consideration since you say that you have many windows open and many processes running.  To keep an eye on the health of your current environment, it would be advisable to have the System Monitor GUI open on your screen.

In recent years, Firefox had devolved into bloatware.  You might try installing LibreWolf which is Firefox without the bloatware.  I've been using Mozilla for well over a decade and recently shifted to LibreWolf.  The transition is absolutely seamless and LibreWolf uses only a fraction of the resources that FF does.

If you don't want to do that, even as a test, adding more resources like more/faster RAM, a larger/faster swapfile, a faster drive/CPU/Graphics card will likely solve your problem.

You didn't mention in your question the age of your computer. If it's old it just may not be able to keep up with Mozilla's desire to constantly fatten up their resource hog apps.

The syslog entry looks to be a notification that a requested resource was never served up.  Or not served up in a timely manner so FF just took a permanent siesta.

Comment: It's not a resource issue though, I've had the same happen on my system, 16GB RAM; sometimes it did happen when I was running too much junk and had some swapping (I'm upgrading to a newer system with 32GB very soon), I thought it probably bits of browser being swapped out or whatever.  But other times it was firefox alone, something like 13GB+ free RAM while it's running, and still got the either total freeze or ridiculously slow text entry box, which does not clear up until I quit (or kill) and restart firefox.

Comment: FWIW, I have been managing *NIX systems since BSD came out in 1972.  I know resource starvation symptoms when I see them.  16G of RAM is totally insufficient for a modern Ubuntu desktop.  Will it run?  Sure.  Will it run fast and reliably?  Nope.  I run high end mobos and 64G of RAM with very large SSD swapfiles and rarely encounter freezes or hangs and even then the issue is usually a sw bug.  FF has become bloatware.  Having to kill FF to restore the machine to normal makes my point.  So please upvote my answer :)

Comment: Upvoted!  Whether FF118-119 has a new bug or not causing freezes, the fact of the matter is FF is a major resource hog.  (Whether FF is just plain bloated; or if it's bloated web pages, javascript, and tabs bloating things up, the result is the same.)  I also have this strong suspicion that FF's garbage collection has it walking through memory, resulting in any FF-related data that got swapped out getting swapped back in whether FF is presently using it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue: `sudo apt install --reinstall firefox`

If the issue still persists, please [try this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-crashes-closing-or-quitting#w_check-to-see-if-the-crash-happens-in-troubleshoot-mode)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think either of your suggestions are applicable here.
My Firefox was installed through snap, so I'd have to uninstall it using snap (which I currently can't) before installing it again using apt.
And my Firefox doesn't crash; it keeps running but simply becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Are you in the latest version of firefox?

Answer (score 0):

After clearing all history data and cookies since the beginning the problem is solved in my case. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read system logs, for example

```
/var/log/syslog
```

In my case of freezing firefox there was an error:

```
iommu ivhd0: amd-vi: event logged [invalid_device_request]
```

I resolve this issue by editing /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet amd_iommu=off ..."
```

plus

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now firefox works fine on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Note that the OP has already solved the problem which was due to history and/or cookies.